# How can I switch the active interpreter/Conda environment when switching branches in VS Code?

Tags: python, git, visual-studio-code, anaconda, ide

I have two separate branches in the same repo that require different Conda environments in order to run the code on each branch. Each time I switch branch I need to manually set the active workspace interpreter to the relevant Conda environment. Is there any way to automate this so that VS Code keeps a record of the interpreter used for each branch and switches interpreter automatically whenever I switch branch?

At present I've simply been manually setting the interpreter each time using the Python: Environments menu.

Comment: If you create corresponding workspaces for different branches and set up Python interpreters for each workspace, when you switch workspaces, vscode will automatically switch the Python interpreter for you. Can this meet your needs?

Comment: Would this require setting up separate git worktrees? This isn't something I've worked with before but looks like it would solve my problem, albeit a bit more inconveniently than being able to use the same workspace (I only need the secondary branch to review PRs). Would using a multi-root workspace with separate git worktrees in the same repository be an option?